# Is there a way to get the open call to work properly?

Tags: c

i working on a shell program and i need to to do redirection. i am having 2 issues. first being when i try to open the file that the user enters, it is always -1 and i dont know what i did. it was working at one point and now its not. i am not sure where my mistake is because it is a simple line of code and also, when i use dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) what is my next move? do i need to do anything else specific or just let it run on through the program searching for the command?

```
        if ((fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC,0600)) < 0) {
            printf("error opening file");
            continue;
        }
        else {
            if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
                printf("error copying file");
                continue;
```

Comment: When `open` returns `-1`, what is the value of `errno`?

Comment: Use [`perror`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) instead of `printf` to see what's actually wrong.